# ReSharper suggests to convert Model Classes to abstract class, should I?

Tags: c#, resharper

I have Model Classes, for example:

```
 public class Data
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int Age{ get; set; }
}
```

ReShaper suggests, that I should use an abstract class here. Is that really something I should do?

Comment: There is a possibility that, you are using some kind of automapper and this calls is not getting instantiated anywhere and result of that ReSharper saying make is abstract.

Comment: Rule #1 - don't believe everything the ReSharper tells you.

Comment: Yes, it's still a suggestions :)

Comment: @Bharat that makes sense, as I am using the classes for Dapper. I will add these classes to ignored code. Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Typically, when ReSharper is not able to find the classes being instantiated anywhere in the solution it suggests to make it abstract. Like in model like classes, if we use Aumapper/Dapper, ReSharper whon't see any instance being made.

Having said that, like @Neil said, ReSharper is a code assisting tool and makes lots of suggestions, don't believe everything it says. You could add these classes to ignored list.